# How to give exact height value to DraggableScrollableSheet in flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget, draggable

I have simple `DraggableScrollableSheet` in flutter and it has parameter like `initialChieldSize`, `minChildSize`, `maxChildSize` but they take value in ftaction of parent height.

But I have fix height Elements and want to give exact height in value to `initialChildSize`.

how to give exact value to the above parameters in `DraggableScrollableSheet`?

Answer (score 3):

Try getting MediaQuery's size or any other custom parent widget's size (use Layout Builder for custom size). Then give the DraggableScrollableSheet initial and min child size of <you_desired_height> / size.height. This way you will get what the fraction for this particular height is. It worked for me :)

Here is an example:

```
return LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, safeAreaSize) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Placeholder(),
        Positioned.fill(
          child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
            initialChildSize: 40 / safeAreaSize.maxHeight,
            minChildSize: 40 / safeAreaSize.maxHeight,
            maxChildSize: 1.0,
            expand: false,
            builder: (context, scrollController) {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: scrollController,
                child: Container(height: 40).backgroundColor(Colors.blue),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
```

If you want to see it in action go to:
https://dartpad.dev/d89a5411bb9785edfb630f6082b71d00

Edit: I found a package called "sliding_sheet" on pub.dev and it's neat. It can auto-resize the sheet based on content, and it can snap at places you want on the screen. I give the same value as in above code to the first of "snappings" (it's an argument to SlidiingSheet contructor). Hope you will find it useful!